# App to view PDF files

Tags: ipad, pdf

I want to create an app that will allow users to view and print from a selection of PDF files. Can anyone suggest a platform that I should use?

I have all the PDF files and want to allow my users to access them via the iPad.

Answer (score 2):

My suggestion would be to make the PDF files available online as iBooks already acts as a way to download, display, and email PDFs on the iPad. Although iBooks does not let you edit the PDF files.